# Grab full regex word if pattern inside it matches

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I retrieve an entire word that has a specific portion of it that matches a regex?

For example, I have the below text.
Using `^.[\.\?\!:;,]{2,}` , I match the first 3, but not the last. The last should be matched as well, but $ doesn't seem to produce anything.

```
a!!!!!!
n.......
c..,;,;,,

huhuhu..
```

I want to get all strings that have an occurrence of certain characters equal to or more than twice. I produced the aforementioned regex, but on Rubular it only matches the characters themselves, not the entire string. Using ^ and $

I've read a few stackoverflow posts similar, but not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do? or the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to:

```
/^.*[.?!:;,]{2,}/gm
```

i.e. match 0 more character before 2 of those special characters.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qY4vJ4/2)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well you are trying to match an entire string that contains at least the same punctuation character two times:

```
^.*?([.?!:;,])\1.*
```

Note: if your string has newline characters, change `.*` to `[\s\S]*`

The trick is here:

```
([.?!:;,])   # captures the punct character in group 1
\1           # refers to the character captured in group 1
```